# Janky response: Unknown repository :'myrepo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, hubot, janky

I take unknown repository error when I build my Github repo on campfire like below:

```
hubot ci build scholar
Unknown repository: "scholar"
```

Here my Janky heroku logs:

```
2013-02-26T07:53:58+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
path=/_hubot/uygulama/master?room_id=552860&user=jankycamp
host=jankycamp.herokuapp.com fwd="204.236.210.215" dyno=web.1 queue=0
wait=0ms connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=30'
```

I get the status 404 in this log. Im realy bogged down and can't solve this issue. Waiting for your ideas.

Comment: Make sure you've ran your setup first. - hubot ci setup user/repo - and that that's returned properly first.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only job that you have, you may want to validate your setup.

I would:
- make sure that my project setup looks correct and go through janky documentation once again to see if I may have missed a step
- go through the logical chain of access and validate if the various services are running and available/accessible (janky, jenkins, github repo)
- validate through the console of jenkins that I have the jobs that I expect

Usually, looking at the logs/consoles of mentioned applications can give you a better clue.

If your happen to have other jobs and this one is the only that is unavailable, I would look at the permissions primarily.